# Unable to sort date in java using android studio

Tags: java, android, text

I want to sort my array based on their latest dates. I am retrieving the date as a string from a text file. My text file is a follows:

```
title:High Five
date:02-04-2019
title:Roly Poly
date:04-07-2019
title:Barney
date:11-01-2016
```

I want to display them as follows:

```
title:Roly Poly
date:04-07-2019
title:High Five
date:02-04-2019
title:Barney
date:11-01-2016
```

I have use the following method:

```
public class mydateCompare implements Comparator<Cartoon>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Cartoon o1, Cartoon o2) {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        String dateinString = o1.getDate();
        String dateinS = o2.getDate();

        try {
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateinString);
            Date dt = dateFormat.parse(dateinS);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dateinString.compareTo(dateinS);

    }
}
```

My output from the above method is:

```
title:High Five
date:02-04-2019
title:Roly Poly
date:04-07-2019
title:Barney
date:11-01-2016
```

Can you guys tell me what I need to do the get my desired output? Thank you.

Comment: you are not using parsed dated in compare methods.use them instead of strings

Comment: 1. As said, you are comparing Strings and not dates (calling dateinString.compareTo instead of your date object)
2. You are capturing any exception but continue executing the function, that's generally a source of bugs, say your 2nd is not ok, you'll catch the parsing exception but crash / not compare properly later on when comparing since the 2nd date is invalid

Comment: Your first mistake is to design dates as strings in your `Cartoon` class. The second mistake is to use the old deprecated API for dates and times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are comparing the strings which sorts the entries incorrectly. I suggest that you parse the strings to `LocalDate` from the Java 8 Date/Time API with a custom formatter. The (unchecked) exception should be handled outside the comparator since you cannot compare the entries without the parsed date.

As a side-note, it would be better to already use parsed dates in your `Cartoon` object.

Here is an example for the comparator:

```
public class CartoonDescendingDateComparator implements Comparator<Cartoon> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

    @Override
    public int compare(Cartoon o1, Cartoon o2) {
        LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse(o1.getDate(), DATE_FORMATTER);
        LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse(o2.getDate(), DATE_FORMATTER);
        return d2.compareTo(d1); // descending order
    }

}
```

Here is a test case with your data:

```
List<Cartoon> cartoons = new ArrayList<>();
cartoons.add(new Cartoon("High Five", "02-04-2019"));
cartoons.add(new Cartoon("Roly Poly", "04-07-2019"));
cartoons.add(new Cartoon("Barney", "11-01-2016"));

cartoons.sort(new CartoonDescendingDateComparator());

cartoons.forEach(c -> System.out.println("title:" + c.getTitle() + "\ndate:" + c.getDate()));
```

Output:

```
title:Barney
date:11-01-2016
title:High Five
date:02-04-2019
title:Roly Poly
date:04-07-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy the class below,

```
internal class CartoonsSorter : Comparator<Cartoon> {

        private val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

        override fun compare(o1: Cartoon, o2: Cartoon): Int {
            var firstObjDate = Date()
            var secondObjDate = Date()
            try {
                firstObjDate = dateFormat.parse(o1.date) ?: Date()
                secondObjDate = dateFormat.parse(o2.date) ?: Date()

            } catch (e: ParseException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            return secondObjDate.compareTo(firstObjDate)
        }
    }
```

Use it in the below way,

```
Collections.sort(yourArray, CartoonsSorter())
```

**Output for the above:**

Before Sorting:

```
[
  {
    "date": "02-04-2019",
    "title": "High Five"
  },
  {
    "date": "04-07-2019",
    "title": "Roly Poly"
  },
  {
    "date": "11-01-2016",
    "title": "Barney"
  }
]
```

After Sorting:

```
[
  {
    "date": "04-07-2019",
    "title": "Roly Poly"
  },
  {
    "date": "02-04-2019",
    "title": "High Five"
  },
  {
    "date": "11-01-2016",
    "title": "Barney"
  }
]
```